# Zynq 7020 system generator start up problem

Tags: matlab, vivado

I have recently started using Xilinx system generator for simulating  dvb communications system.

Matlab 2014b and Vivado 2014.4 were installed and everything was running smoothly with no problem.

At some point I needed Vivado 2013.4 to be installed in my laptop,and then the day after when I run the system generator the initial system generator window pops up but matlab fails to load without any error to be displayed or any other notification.
Any idea on how to proceed?Is it any file that system generator uses to call matlab  that needs to e configured (any kind of path misplaced)?
Did anyone ever had a similar problem?

Regards
George

Comment: I've never used that exact combination of tools but in the past I've seen some versions that create long entries in the PATH environment variable that don't get cleared on upgrades / reinstalls. Maybe that's worth checking: http://superuser.com/questions/635082/too-many-folders-in-the-path-variable

Answer (score 1):

The solution was given by "hacking" the system generator batch file,and giving the direct path somewhere related to the licence,while that was given through a variable which was wrong.I needed to replace that and point to the directory where my licence file was,without using that variable.